# How to resolve this java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'on a null object reference?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-biometric-prompt

I've implemented the fingerprint feature into my Android app and I'm using jetpack compose. This is my Biometric code.

```
import android.content.Context 
import android.os.Build 
import android.util.Log 
import android.widget.Toast 
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager 
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt 
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable 
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext 
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat 
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity 
import sahalwallet.app.R 
import sahalwallet.app.theme.bu 
import sahalwallet.app.theme.col 
import sahalwallet.app.theme.ui

class Biometric:FragmentActivity() {


    fun status(con: Context): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(con)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL or BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED ->
                    result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED ->
                    result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_STATUS_UNKNOWN ->
                    result = false
            }
        } else {
            when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> result = false
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED ->
                    result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED ->
                    result = true
                BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_STATUS_UNKNOWN ->
                    result = false
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    fun authenticate(
        activity: FragmentActivity,
        title: String,
        otherOption: String,
        onError: (Int, CharSequence) -> Unit,
        onSuccess: (BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) -> Unit,
        onFailed: () -> Unit,
    ) {
        Log.d("activity is =>",activity.toString())
        val executor =ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)

        val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity, executor,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(
                    errorCode: Int,
                    errString: CharSequence
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    onError(errorCode, errString)
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                    result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult
                ) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    onSuccess(result)
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    onFailed()
                }
            })
        val promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setNegativeButtonText(otherOption)
            .build()
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)

    }

    @Composable
    fun BiometricUI() {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        if (status(context)) {
            bu.Icon(
                iconEnd = R.drawable.fingerprint,
                round = ui.tinyHeight,
                bg = col.whiteBrush,
                height = 90,
                action = {

                    /**TODO
                     * We need to pass an object of FragmentActivity into the activity parameter
                     */

                    authenticate(
                        activity = this@Biometric,
                        title = "Authentication Required",
                        otherOption = "Password",
                        onSuccess = {
                            runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Authenticated successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                )
                                    .show() //                                isAuthenticated.value = true
                            }
                        },
                        onError = { _, _ ->
                            /*
                        On Clicking on Password
                         */

                        },
                        onFailed = {
                            runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Authentication failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                )
                                    .show()

                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    } }

val fingerprint = Biometric()
```

And in my code I'm calling `fingerprint.BiometricUI()`
And I'm using this into some Composable in my code and this is also showing the biometric icon so when I click this the issue is coming:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.concurrent.Executor android.content.Context.getMainExecutor()' on a null object reference

I tried to `activity.mainExecutor` and `ContextCompt.getMainexecutor` but both are giving the same issue!

> java.util.concurrent.Executor android.content.Context.getMainExecutor()

Comment: Can you post the code with proper indentation? It is very hard to read.

Comment: I did right now

Comment: You used the quote feature so it is not properly formatted as code.

Comment: oh! Sorry now it's set.